# umake being unable to install idea-ultimate with python related errors on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3

### Problem

I'm getting this error on `sudo apt install ubuntu-make` (The installation is successful, but It throws this error while doing so)

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/frameworks/ide.py:99: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
```

Then, when trying to install, for example, idea-ultimate, I get this:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py:92: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  self._config = yaml.load(f)
```

and when the installation is about to complete:

```
ERROR: Unhandled exception                #                                    |
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 158, in wrapper
    function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/frameworks/baseinstaller.py", line 457, in decompress_and_install_done
    add_exec_link(self.exec_path, self.exec_link_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 343, in add_exec_link
    add_env_to_user("Ubuntu Make binary symlink", {"PATH": {"value": bin_folder}})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 439, in add_env_to_user
    remove_framework_envs_from_user(framework_tag)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/umake/tools.py", line 423, in remove_framework_envs_from_user
    with open(profile_filepath + ".new", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jasper/.profile.new'
```

### Possible issues:

- I recently changed my user name and the home directory via `usermod`. (This is mentioned because umake promts me to install idea-ultimate in my old `home/jasper-ubuntu` directory (now it's `home/jasper`)
- Python is incorrectly installed. (This is mentioned because earlier today, I installed and then uninstalled (via `rm -rf /home/jasper/anaconda3`) Anaconda3. (`python -V` returns `Python 3.8.6`, and `python2 -V` returns `Python 2.7.18`.

### Troubleshooting

I've tried basic troubleshooting like removing umake and reinstalling, but I didn't want to touch python at all because there's a high chance I'll mess it up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend installing using the [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/download/download-thanks.html). This will also ensure you have a simple way to update or uninstall the IDE.

1. Download using the link above.
2. Go to the Tools tab and pick IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Let me know as a comment if it fails.

Comment: I'll try it out in a second, much appreciated <3. But is there a possibility my python installation is wrong because of the user rename? I'm concerned that + the Anaconda3 installation and uninstallation may have caused issues with Python somehow.

Comment: Absolutely. I see 2 distinct problems: the version of Python seems to be off, and there is a permission error. None of these seem hard to fix but I find it extremely hard to even point you to the the diagnostics steps due to many ways they might be off. Don't worry, one step at a time. Maybe Toolbox installs IntelliJ sufficiently different to make it work.

Comment: I've been able to install idea through the toolbox, thanks.
Any idea on how could I receive help about my python issue? Once again, thanks in a advance

Comment: I suggest you check if all files in your home directory are owned by you. Run this in your Bash terminal: `ls -GlR ~ | grep -vE 'total |'$(whoami)'|:$|^$'`. If it outputs something, you can take back ownership with `sudo chown $(whoami) ~ -R`. This might resolve the "Permission denied: '/home/jasper/.profile.new'" from your question.

Comment: I figured it out literally some minutes before your answer! Thank you very much. If I weren't been able to find out myself this comment would have saved my day. <3 
Credited you in this other issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321437/issues-with-python-and-potentially-other-programs-after-home-directory-change/1321471#1321471).